# Add ng-click like an attribute AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm wondering is a way to add an `ng-click` as an attribute?

Let's say I want to add `ng-click` if my `<li>` has a class `someClass`:

```
angular.element(root.querySelector('li.someClass').attr({'ng-click': 'someFunc()'});
```

And when `<li>` has a class `anotherClass` I want to reset the ng-click:

```
angular.element(root.querySelector('li.someClass').attr({'ng-click': ''});
```

But it didn't work.

I can't make it in my HTML:

```
<li class="someClass" ng-click="someFunc()"> ... </li>
<li class="anotherClass"> ... </li>
```

because my HTML is generated dynamically by `ng-repeat` and also there is a directive which make some mess with `ng-hide`.

The best solution will be with the `angular.element` but `ng-click` isn't an attribute right?

(I can debug the code in Visual Studio and when I add `ng-click` in a way `<li ng-click="someFunc()">...</li>` I can't find it in the `Locals Window` in VS)

Comment: ng-click isn't a "real" attribute. It is an angular directive. Adding it via angular.element or jquery will not make angular run it. Could you give your ng-repeat and what is wrong with it ? We could fix that instead of trying to do some things in a non-angular way :).

Answer (score 1):

Check the class name in handler function instead reset ng-click

JS

```
$scope.someFunc = function (e) {

    if(angular.element(e.target).hasClass("someClass")){
        //code goes here
    };
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="someClass" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">Button</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really toggle `ng-click` since it's a angular directive but you can add conditions like so:

```
<li ng-click="someVar === true ? callOnMe() : ''">CLICK ME</li>
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnrL6cLw/

*Note: Change `$scope.someVar` to be true to see the alert.*

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `ng-repeat` code, it's hard to say - but, if I'm understanding your goal correctly, I think you could use `ng-switch` with `ng-switch-when` to achieve the output you want:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch="item.someCondition">
    <li ng-switch-when="true" class="someClass" ng-click="someFunc()">...</li>
    <li ng-switch-when="false" class="anotherClass">...</li>
</ul>
```

That way it should render the list item you want to display based upon the condition. Of course, `item.someCondition` doesn't have to be a boolean value - you could match on a string, int, or any other type you like.